# Specifying multiple "through" tables on the same field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a Django model with two ManyToManyFields that point to the same field.

In my example, Talents and Interests are both "Skills" but have a different through table.

```
class Skills(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, default=None,
            through='TalentDetails', related_name='talents')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, default=None,
            through='InterestDetails', related_name='interests')
```

I get an error when trying to access talents through its related name

```
UserProfile.interests.all()    #[<Skills: Guitar>]
UserProfile.talents.all() # AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'talents'
# the following works
UserProfile.talentdetails_set.all() # [<TalentDetails: (u'Architecture',)>]
```

So a couple of questions:

- Why does the second query fail?
- Is this a kosher way of specifying multiple 'through' tables on the same field or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two model fields with the same name, `users`, the second one (to InterestDetails) is replacing the first one, just give them different names and it'll work.

Comment: true. But I want to avoid using two fields (eg. user and user_<foo>) to specify the same relation (user). If I specify the relationship to not be symmetrical, could I get the Skill field to use two different "through" tables in its relation with UserProfile?

Comment: I think we need to better understand the overall problem you're trying to model here, it feels like you might be trying to solve it in the wrong way.

Comment: That might very well be. I'm building a Talent/Interests directory. Talents and Interests both represent a relation from a Skill to a Profile. The details of this relationship are captured in the [Talent|Skill]Details tables. Right now, I'm trying to create two "through" tables from Skill to Profile to model this relationship. I suppose I could just use one "through" table with a flag for whether its a Talent/Skill but that's not a very elegant solution...

Comment: I share the sentiment of flags not being very elegant, but I think in this case it makes sense. It simplifies the data model and will help with database queries too.

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking really doesn't make sense. Obviously, a field can only have one set of options, and you're trying to have two sets. But it's not clear why you want to do that: I understand that both fields are linking the same two tables, but they're modelling different things: the first field is 'users who have this Skill as a Talent' and the other is 'users who have this Skill as an Interest'. For that reason, you should have two fields, both pointing at UserProfile but with different names - eg `users_with_talent` and `users_with_interest`.

(Note that unless you're defining extra information on the relationship, you don't need to define the through table explicitly.)